# Automatic space when typesetting block matrix

Tags: matrices, typography, nicematrix

Is there an easy way to create block matrices which automatically adjust size based on their content? MWE using the `nicematrix` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{pNiceArray}{cc|c}
    \Block{2-2}{A_\lambda(\sigma) B_\mu(\tau)} & & 0 \\
    & & 0 \\ \hline
    0 & 0 & 1
\end{pNiceArray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Obviously, the first two columns need a larger width, and we *could* manually adjust them. If we wanted to adjust only the first two, it would take a small bit more work than adjusting all columns at once.

But why is it so complicated? Why isn't there, for example, a key we could simply set to true in order to scale the rows and columns according to the contents of the blocks?

Or is there a simple way to do this, perhaps using another package?

Edit: answer is not required to be simple, necessarily. If there's a technical difficulty with TeX or some other obstacle, an explanation would suffice/be nice. But otherwise, why isn't there a package yet?!

Comment: Welcome! There is no package because nobody has written one or, if they have, they have kept it to themselves. Almost all packages are written by people who are in precisely your position: they want a package which doesn't exist. Some of those people write the packages they want. Some of those who write the packages they want publish them. Packages are just scratches answering itches. There is no answer this site can give to your question. You are asking about the motivations of people who haven't done something. I'm one of them; you're another. I haven't as I've no need. Why haven't you?

Comment: As to why there isn't a key in `nicematrix`. That's a question for the author, but I suspect the answer is: because it would make things still more complex and correspondingly slower.

Comment: Maybe `tabularray` can already do what you want? // That having said, more often than not the answer is "the number of people who deeply understand TeX enough to write packages for it is very small, and because of how difficult TeX programming is, they find writing a package more trouble than manually specifying the width"

Comment: @cfr Perhaps I haven't because I am relatively new to TeX...?

Comment: I'm also not sure where you are getting that I am asking about (individual) motivations. Rather, this seems to me an obvious utility that anyone writing block matrices might desire, and, as such, seems the sort of thing that a package would have been written for already (TeX is 40!). So, I was guessing, there might be a technical difficulty (which is clearly a well-defined question with well-defined answer).

Comment: @user202729 Thanks for your reply. It seems `tabularray` does work with the `\SetCell` command. If you make an answer I will accept it (and I can add a MWE to it).

Comment: @myca Which is perfectly reasonable. It's just that your question came across as 'why hasn't this been done?' which is a question about why nobody has voluntarily created something you happen to want. Also, TeX may be 40, but LaTeX is (a bit) younger and `nicematrix` is very young. `\Block` was introduced in version 3.1, but package development is quite rapid in terms of version nos. The code also uses `expl3` syntax extensively, which makes programming easier but is (1) pretty new & (2) still undergoing rapid development. Perhaps the answer's that it'll get included as tools become available?

Comment: To be fair, you might say that the technical difficulty with TeX is *programming in TeX itself* --- that's what I usually say, but then one disadvantage of tabularray is that synctex information is lost and verbatim can't be used inside table cell, and I can't quite explain why other than "I can't come up with any way to implement the feature other than by taken the whole cell content, and if I do that the two points above follows naturally"

Comment: @user202729 In particular, writing a package you're happy publishing is a whole different thing than writing one for yourself. It's not enough to make it work. And sometimes things which might be useful to other people are entangled with things which surely won't be. Another possibility: I wrote a parasitic class which I know other people might use (there is a Word template and there were requests for a LaTeX class). I intended to, but I found out I've coded it wrongly. It works, so I've not got around to redoing it correctly, but I don't want to publish something I know needs redoing.

Comment: Thanks for your comments folks. I see how my question may have come across in a certain way, but I was only intending to express surprise—in any case, the main question was really 'is there a way this can be done?', which was answered in the affirmative by @user202729.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @user202729: this can be achieved using the `tabularray` package with the `\SetCell` command. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{+pmatrix}
    \SetCell[r=2,c=2]{c} A_\lambda(\sigma) B_\mu(\tau) & & \vline 0 \\
    & & 0 \\ \hline
    0 & 0 & 1
\end{+pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```